# Django form is not submitted to the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am writing a Django website for dentists, the dentist can register patients with form easily not an issue, however when registering visits for a patient it is not saved, in the admin panel both  models works just fine, on the website the visits form dose not save to database.

---

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Paitent(models.Model):

pname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
age = models.IntegerField()
gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
telephone = models.IntegerField()
mHistory = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)   


def __str__(self):
    return self.pname

class Visit(models.Model):
paitent = models.ForeignKey(Paitent,null=True ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
toothNumber = models.CharField('involved tooth', max_length=120)
cComplaint = models.CharField('chief complaint',max_length=120)
sASymptoms = models.CharField('signs and symptoms',max_length=120)
diagnosis = models.CharField(max_length=120)
procedure = models.CharField(max_length=120)
notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
currentVisit = models.DateTimeField(
    'time and date of current visit', null=True)
nextAppointment = models.DateTimeField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.toothNumber
```

---

**forms.py**

```
 from django import forms
 from .models import Paitent
 from .models import Visit


 class PaitentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Paitent
         fields = ['pname', 'age', 'gender', 'address', 'telephone']
    
 class VisitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Visit
         fields = ['paitent', 'toothNumber', 'cComplaint',
              'sASymptoms', 'diagnosis', 'procedure',
              'notes', 'currentVisit', 'nextAppointment']
```

---

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Paitent
from .models import Visit
from .forms import PaitentForm
from .forms import VisitForm
import calendar
from calendar import HTMLCalendar


def homePage(request):
    all_paitents = Paitent.objects.all
    return render (request, 'homePage.html',{'all':all_paitents})

def newpaitent(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PaitentForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
    return render(request, 'newpaitent.html', {})
        
else:
    return render(request, 'newpaitent.html', {})


def addVisit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VisitForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
        return render(request, 'addVisit.html', {})

else:
    return render(request, 'addVisit.html', {})
```

---

template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'  %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/addVisit.css">
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/e662339992c4abf5b43f537391bd3169? 
     family=Candara" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
    <title>Add Visit</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Title navbar -->

<div class="titleContainer">

    <h1> Clinic Name </h1>
    <h2> Dental Clinic. </h2>

</div>

<!-- Drop down menu -->

    <div class="drop_down_menu hidden buttons_container">
        <p id="add_appointment"> <a href="/"> Home </a></p>
        <hr id="hr_line">
        <p id="calender"> <a href="/calendar"> Calender </a></p>

</div>

<!-- Form -->

    <h4 class="h4_text"> Add Current Visit : </h4>

    <form class="form_container" method="POST" action="{% url 'addVisit' 
      %}">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{form.as_p}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <input  class="form-control" name="paitent">
    </div>

    <label> Involved Tooth :</label>
    <div class="chart_container form-group">
        <div class="chart_item upper_right_quardent">
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UR8')">8</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UR7')">7</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UR6')">6</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UR5')">5</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UR4')">4</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UR3')">3</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UR2')">2</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UR1')">1</option>
        </div>

        <div class="chart_item upper_left_quardent">
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UL1')">1</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UL2')">2</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UL3')">3</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UL4')">4</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UL5')">5</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UL6')">6</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UL7')">7</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('UL8')">8</option>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="chart_line hidden"> </div>
    <div class="chart_line vertical_line hidden"> </div>

    <div class="chart_container">
        <div class="chart_item lower_right_quardent">
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LR8')">8</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LR7')">7</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LR6')">6</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LR5')">5</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LR4')">4</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LR3')">3</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LR2')">2</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LR1')">1</option>
        </div>

        <div class="chart_item lower_left_quardent">
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LL1')">1</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LL2')">2</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LL3')">3</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LL4')">4</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LL5')">5</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LL6')">6</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LL7')">7</option>
            <option onclick="toothNumber('LL8')">8</option>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="toothNumber" name="toothNumber" placeholder="Tooth Number">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="non-chart">

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ccomplain" name="cComplaint" placeholder="Chief Complaint">
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="dropdown" class="form-control" id="sasymptoms" name="sASymptoms" placeholder="Signs and Symptoms">
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-group">
    
        <input class="form-control" list="diagnosis" name="diagnosis" placeholder="Diagnosis" />

        <datalist id="diagnosis">
            <option value="Bad Oral Hygien"></option>
            <option value="Gingivitis"></option>
            <option value="Periodentits"></option>
            <option value="dental Stain"></option>
            <option value="dental and Gingival Stain"></option>
            <option value="Mobility"></option>
            <option value="Superficial Caires"></option>
            <option value="Deep Caires"></option>
            <option value="Reversible Pulpitis"></option>
            <option value="Irreversible Pulpitis"></option>
            <option value="Necrotic"></option>
            <option value="Retained Root"></option>
        </datalist>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            
        <input class="form-control" list="procedure" name="procedure" placeholder="Procedure" required />
            
            <datalist id="procedure">
                <option value="Treatment"></option>
                <option value="Scalling and Polishing"></option>
                <option value="Deep Scalling and polishing"></option>
                <option value="Whitening"></option>
                <option value="Direct Pulp Capping"></option>
                <option value="Indirect Pulp Capping"></option>
                <option value="Amlgam Filling"></option>
                <option value="Composite Filling"></option>
                <option value="Build Up"></option>
                <option value="RCT"></option>
                <option value="Crown Preparation"></option>
                <option value="Extraction"></option>
            </datalist>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        
            <input class="form-control notes" name="notes" placeholder="Notes"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <label class="appointment_label"> Current Visit Date :</label>
    <div class="form-group appointment">
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="current_visit" name="currentVisit" required>
    </div>

    <label class="appointment_label"> Next Appointment :</label>
    <div class="form-group appointment">
            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" 
     id="appointment" 
    name="nextAppointment">
        </div>
     
        <div class="bottom_button_cotainer">
            <a href="javascript:history.back() " class="btn btn-danger button"> 
    cancel </a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-group button"> 
    Submit </button>
        </div>

    </form>


    <script>
    

    function toothNumber(string) {
    document.getElementById("toothNumber").value = string;
            }
    </script>


    
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homePage, name='homePage'),
    path('newpaitent', views.newpaitent, name='newpaitent'),
    path('calendar', views.calendar, name='calendar'),
    path('paitentInfo', views.paitentInfo, name='paitentInfo'),
    path('addVisit', views.addVisit, name='addVisit'),
    path('paitentInfoSearched', views.paitentInfoSearched,
         name='paitentInfoSearched'),
    path('visits', views.visits, name='visits')
```

---

thank you in advance

Comment: please provide newpaitent.html template

Comment: Also share your urls.py

Comment: In which page do you want to redirect after submitting the VisitForm?

Comment: @SunderamDubey same page// or any it dosent really matter

Comment: Does the issue is only with redirection or it is also not saving data to db?

Comment: @MuhammedAlkawaz also share main project urls

Comment: @SunderamDubey Yes right, the issue is with only redirection so that's why it is not saving data to db

Comment: @ManojTolagekar But see comment of OP below your answer where he said **Thanks a lot , although it still not working but the problem is defiantly with the form, it is not saving it keeps returning me to the form page**?

Comment: @SunderamDubey but there is nothing wrong with form

Comment: I think the form is not saving data for some reason, the console says that form is posted, but in back end no changes happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't provide context in view:

Instead of this:

```
def addVisit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VisitForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
        return render(request, 'addVisit.html', {})

    else:
         return render(request, 'addVisit.html', {})
```

try this:

```
     def addvisit(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = VisitForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
               try:
                   form.save()
                   return redirect("/") #Add your project route here where you want to go after adding visitors
               except:
                    pass
        else:
             form = VisitForm()  
        return render(request, 'addvisit.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Yes that's right but if that's the thing, so form does not also show in frontend, the OP says it is not saving to the db only.

Comment: @SunderamDubey but he didn't pass any context so how he got form to the front-end

Comment: Yes that's what I'm thinking. It seems that there are typos while writing the question.

Comment: the new patient form is working fine, I am having problem with the visit form

Comment: @MuhammedAlkawaz Updated checkout

Comment: Thanks a lot , although it still not working but the problem is defiantly with the form, it is not saving it keeps returning me to the form page

Comment: please provide addvisit template

Comment: i have added the template

Answer (score 0):

If the form is not valid, it wont be committed to database.

Print the form errors, this should help you understand why the form is not getting saved

```
if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
else:
          print(form.errors)
```

Comment: it says: [07/Oct/2022 12:11:54] "POST /addVisit HTTP/1.1" 200 6944